# Add a Null column to a linq query

Tags: linq

I want to do a LINQ query and add in a column that is null. Something like this:

```
        var query = (from all in data
                                    select new
                                    {
                                        all.Column1,
                                        all.Column2,
                                        all.Column3,
                                        newColumn = null
                                    })
```

However, this gives me the error "cannot assign null to anonymous type property".

Comment: Why would you even want to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the null with appropriate cast depending on the type of newColumn such as e.g. `newColumn = (string) null;`